# Ubuntu's max resolution is 1024x768 (unknown monitor)

Tags: ubuntu, display, ubuntu-13.04

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 and the max resolution it's letting me choose for the monitor I currently have plugged in - a 1280x1024 monitor - is 1024x768. The description for the Monitor is "Unknown". See attached:

[image: Unknown monitor]

The monitor is an IBM ThinkVision L170P.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From https://askubuntu.com/questions/139947/why-cant-ubuntu-12-04-detect-my-screen-resolution

Open your terminal and run this:

```
xrandr --newmode $(cvt 1280 1024 60 | grep Mode | sed -e 's/.*"/1280x1024/')
```

Comment: I had to do `xrandr --addmode VGA1 1280x1024` as well but otherwise your solution worked!

Comment: xrandr --newmode $(cvt 1920 1080 60 | grep Mode | sed -e 's/.*"/1920x1080/')

Comment: It worked, but why I have to run it every time the system starts?

Comment: after I did this, my monitors keep blinking out, I lose my second display then my background turns into a noisy pattern.  Also, sometimes when I log out the next time I log in, it's almost a blank screen but I can get back in if I just type my password.

Answer (score 14):

First type `xrandr -q` to see your valid screen outputs eg. VGA1/DVI-1 etc...
Then `xrandr --addmode DVI-1 1600x1200`
Then new option will appear in your Displays configuration
Tested on ubuntu 14.04 and 2 screens ;)
note this change is not persistent after restart. To make it persistent I made shell script which do above mentioned command `xrandr --addmode...` and then I add line to file `/etc/lightdm` as follows

> [SeatDefaults]
>   display-setup-script=pathToYourScript

this way new resolution is added before desktop try to set it...

Comment: Just to add, make sure that "pathToYourScript" is executable. You can place it in `/opt/` also.

Comment: Does not work. I get error `xrandr: cannot find mode "1920x1080"`

Answer (score 7):

For 1920x1080 res 60 Hz use following:

```
xrandr --newmode $(cvt 1920 1080 60 | grep Mode | sed -e 's/.*"/1920x1080/')
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1920x1080
```

One may encounter different output names: VGA1, VGA-1, etc.

More info [HERE](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr).

Comment: This appears to duplicate the accepted answer plus the OP's comment, only this version has the wrong resolution.

Comment: The issue is that one comment mentiones VGA1 in addmode, in my case it's VGA-1 .
And I have to get new resolution to work.It's just putting together nuances that may help others.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing mesa-utils using `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`.

Once you have this installed reboot your machine. After rebooting the machine open a terminal and type `glxinfo | grep render` and `glxgears`

That should fix it.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu LiveCD on this particular machine so that wouldn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: i don't think this is relevant. not working also.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with LG FLATRON E2241 in my ubuntu 20.04 and the resolution was on 1280x1024. I want to increase that to 1920x1080 so I used this command:

```
xrandr -q
```

The output was:

> Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 16384 x 16384
> eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
> 1920x1080     60.00 +  59.97    59.96    59.93
> 1680x1050     59.95    59.88
> 1600x1024     60.17
> 1400x1050     59.98
> 1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82
> 1280x1024     60.02
> 1440x900      59.89
> 1400x900      59.96    59.88
> 1280x960      60.00
> 1440x810      60.00    59.97
> 1368x768      59.88    59.85
> 1360x768      59.80    59.96
> 1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91
> 1152x864      60.00
> 1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74
> 1024x768      60.04    60.00
> 960x720       60.00
> 928x696       60.05
> 896x672       60.01
> 1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82
> 960x600       59.93    60.00
> 960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82
> 800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25
> 840x525       60.01    59.88
> 864x486       59.92    59.57
> 800x512       60.17
> 700x525       59.98
> 800x450       59.95    59.82
> 640x512       60.02
> 720x450       59.89
> 700x450       59.96    59.88
> 640x480       60.00    59.94
> 720x405       59.51    58.99
> 684x384       59.88    59.85
> 680x384       59.80    59.96
> 640x400       59.88    59.98
> 576x432       60.06
> 640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32
> 512x384       60.00
> 512x288       60.00    59.92
> 480x270       59.63    59.82
> 400x300       60.32    56.34
> 432x243       59.92    59.57
> 320x240       60.05
> 360x202       59.51    59.13
> 320x180       59.84    59.32
> HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
> DP-1 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
> 1280x1024     75.02*   60.02
> 1152x864      75.00
> 1024x768      75.03    60.00
> 800x600       75.00    60.32
> 640x480       75.00    59.94
> 720x400       70.08
> HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
> DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
> DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
> DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

After finding my plugged monitor in the list I used this command:

```
xrandr --addmode DP-1 1920x1080
```

This added the resolution on my list and then I activated that.

Comment: does not work, error `xrandr: cannot find mode "1920x1080"`

Answer (score 0):

If setting the resolution from the UI doesn't "stay" and falls back to 1024 then setting it via `xrandr` may do the trick.

First get cvt modeline:

```
cvt 1920 1080 60.0
```

this will produce something similar to this:

```
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz 
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120-hsync +vsync
```

now create a named mode and copy values after the `Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"` above:

```
xrandr --newmode "myMode" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120-hsync +vsync
```

check what's your display's code:

```
xrandr

//will produce something like:
//eDP-1 connected 1024x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 381mm x 214mm
//800x600       60.32    56.25  
//848x480       60.00  
//640x480       59.94
```

the monitor code is `eDP-1` in this case.
Now add the newly created mode to the display:

```
xrandr --addmode eDP-1 myMode
```

And finally set that mode on the display:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode myMode
```

That last line actually does the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type `xrandr -q` to see your connected screen (`VGA-1` in my case). Then execute

```bsh
nano /user/home/reschange.sh
```

and paste this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

gtf 1920 1080 60
 
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080" 172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync

xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1920x1080
```

Save the file, make it executable:

```bsh
chmod +x /user/home/reschange.sh
```

and run:

```bsh
sudo ./user/home/reschange.sh
```

Done! You need to make this script running on startup if you don't want to run it manually every time you start the PC.